# In Django, using urlpatterns, how do I match a url-encoded slash character as part of a parameter?

Tags: django, django-urls

In my [Django app](https://github.com/wikimedia/wikiwho_api) I have these urlpatterns:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', schema_view, name='swagger'),
    url(r'^(?P<page_title>.+)/(?P<rev_id>[0-9]+)/$',
        WhoColorApiView.as_view(), name='wc_page_title_rev_id'),
    url(r'^(?P<page_title>.+)/$',
        WhoColorApiView.as_view(), name='wc_page_title'),
]
```

The second entry will match a path like `/en/whocolor/v1.0.0-beta/my_book_title/1108730659/?origin=*` and the third will match a path like `/en/whocolor/v1.0.0-beta/my_book_title/?origin=*`.

The idea is that it's matching a `page_title` parameter (a Wikipedia article title), and an optional integer `rev_id` (revision id) parameter.

However, it does not work as intended for an article titled "Post-9/11", with path `/en/whocolor/v1.0.0-beta/Post-9%2f11/?origin=*`. I want this *not* to match the second pattern (which gets matched as page_title "Post-9" and rev_id 11), and instead match the third pattern.

I understand why the second pattern should match if the path is `/en/whocolor/v1.0.0-beta/Post-9/11/?origin=*`, but when the title is url-encoded as "Post-9%2f11" it still matches the second pattern instead of continuing on to the third pattern.

How can I make Django treat the url-encoded slash as part of the parameter instead of a path separator?

Comment: To stop fighting "titles written by hands" vs "encoding/decoding urls" there is such a thing as [slug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) and [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) method . Use slugs, not titles for your urls.

Comment: Which django version are you on?

Answer (score 0):

In Django there's something called [Path Converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters).

One of the existing path converters deals with things with slashes

> path - Matches any non-empty string, including the path separator, '/'. This allows you to match against a complete URL path rather than a segment of a URL path as with str.

```
path('<path:page_title>/',
         views.post_detail,
         name='post_detail'),
```

When one uses path one doesn't need to escape anything, and it'll work. There are various cases similar to OP's where Path was used as a solution, such as:

- [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68260137/7109869)
- [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51969638/7109869)
- [Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57626316/7109869)
- [Example 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49588198/7109869)
- [Example 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73555007/7109869.)

---

As Ivan Starostin [mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628806/in-django-using-urlpatterns-how-do-i-match-a-url-encoded-slash-character-as-pa#comment130024086_73628806), OP should actually use the path converter slug.

According to the docs

> A slug is a short label for something, containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens.

For example, `building-your-1st-django-site`.

To do so, it's advisable that OP uses, in the model, a field of type [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield).

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
```

Then in the `urls.py`

```
path('<slug:post>/',
         views.post_detail,
         name='post_detail'),
```

Comment: Will this path converter approach work even when that portion of the path needs to be able to handle a url-encoded slash? In this case, the "page_title" parameter is a Wikipedia article title, and Wikipedia article titles can include a slash (as in the "Post-9/11" example). That's a constraint external to this Django app. All I want to be able to do is *not* convert `%2f` back to a slash before it hits this url pattern matcher, so that it can handle a request for a Wikipedia page that does include a slash in the page title.

Comment: @SageRoss When one uses path one doesn't need to escape anything, and it'll work. See the updated answer with some examples.